# getting ERROR: No build artifacts found while publish the android library to jitpack.io

Tags: android-library, jitpack

I have created a library and published it on jitpack.io but there is some issue not able to figure it out.
Here is my **build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group = 'com.github.Shubhamsdr3:timertextview:'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
 //**.     **//
}
```

**Below is the log file from jitpack.io:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------   
 Kotlin:       1.3.61
 Groovy:       2.5.8
 Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
 JVM:          1.8.0_252 (Private Build 25.252-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.14.63-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 amd64

Getting tasks: ./gradlew tasks --all
0m3.734s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Tasks: install,
Running: ./gradlew clean -Pgroup=com.github.XXXXXX -Pversion=0.1.7 -xtest -xlint install
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
 > Task :clean UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 12s
25 actionable tasks: 22 executed, 3 up-to-date
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
Found artifact: com.github.XXXXXX:timertextview::timertextview:0.1.7
2021-01-02T13:52:06.495618771Z
Exit code: 0

ERROR: No build artifacts found
Expected artifacts in: $HOME/.m2/repository/com/github/XXXXXX/timertextview
```

It used work in it's previous version and suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @EdLee not yet.